# Calling specific fragments onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have created a project in which I am using ViewPager class to add fragments. i successfully added fragments and the app is working fine.

Now I am using options menu to create an index sort of thing so that I can divide all the fragments according to chapters and on clicking a particular item in options menu I can call the fragments related to that chapter only.

Till now I am not able to figure out that how to call specific fragments on selecting a specific item in menu.

Please help.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public void setCurrentItem (int item)
>
> Set the currently selected page. If the ViewPager has already been
>   through its first layout with its current adapter there will be a
>   smooth animated transition between the current item and the specified
>   item.

Call the `setCurrentItem(int pageNumber)` of your `ViewPager` in the  `ListView`'s click handler.

Comment: Thank You so much man. Can't believe I was stuck on this for so long.

Comment: Can I also restrict it? I mean after it goes to a certain fragment it continues till the last fragment. Can i stop it after a certain fragment?

Comment: You mean like go to the previous chapter on back press?

Comment: No. I meant that using some particular fragments for a particular chapter.

Comment: Have you been able to achieve what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: No I have not done it yet. I am just scrolling to the first page of each chapter.